# Type declarations in Template Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, template-haskell

Consider the following type (in Haskell):

```
data CType = CInt | CDouble | CProduct String [(String, CType)]
```

I would like to have a function that would generate corresponding Haskell type declarations. Constructors `CInt` and `CDouble` should correspond to `Int` and `Double` types thus result in no declaration. `(CProduct t ts)` should correspond to the record type with name and constructor defined by `t` and fields defined by `ts` list. For example:

```
ty :: CType
ty = CProduct "Type1" [("proj10", CDouble), ("proj11", CProduct "Type0" [("proj0", CInt)])]
```

should result in two definitions:

```
data Type0 = Type0 {proj0 :: Int}
data Type1 = Type1 {proj10 :: Double, proj11 :: Type0}
```

To define this function I use Template Haskell:

```
genType :: CType -> Q Type
genType CInt = return (ConT ''Int)
genType CDouble = return (ConT ''Double)
genType (CProduct s t) =
    do
      l <- lookupTypeName s
      case l of
        Just sn -> return (ConT sn)
        Nothing ->
            do
              sn <- newName s
              return (ConT sn)

genField :: (String, CType) -> Q VarStrictType
genField (s , t) =
    do
      sn <- newName s
      tn <- genType t
      return (sn, NotStrict, tn)

genDecl :: CType -> Q [Dec]
genDecl CInt = return []
genDecl CDouble = return []
genDecl (CProduct s t) =
    do
      ts <- fmap join . mapM (genDecl . snd) $ t
      res <- lookupTypeName s
      case res of
        Just _ -> return ts
        Nothing ->
            do
              sn <- newName s
              sc <- newName s      
              fn <- mapM genField $ t
              let
                  dt = DataD [] sn [] [RecC sc fn] []
              return (dt : ts)
```

When I invoke the function with `$(genDecl ty)` for `ty :: CType` defined above I get following error:

```
The exact Name ‘Type0_adN6’ is not in scope …
      Probable cause: you used a unique Template Haskell name (NameU), 
      perhaps via newName, but did not bind it
```

But when I generate definitions one by one everything is fine:

```
$(fmap (\[x, y] -> [y]) . genDecl $ ty)

$(genDecl $ ty)
```

**So the question is**: how to properly add type declarations in `Q` monad to generate them all at once?

Comment: in the `$(fmap ...)` case it seems that `Type0` gets defined but not `Type1` - is that right?

Comment: @ErikR, that's right

Comment: perhaps it will help - I added a bunch of trace statements: http://lpaste.net/164713 - didn't see anything obvious though

Answer (score 2):

Here's my assessment of what's happening...

Consider this simplified example which also fails:

```
ty :: CType
ty = CProduct "Type1" [  ("proj11", CProduct "Type0" [("proj0", CInt)]) ]
```

1. `genType` is called with `CProduct "Type1" ...`
2. The declarations for the fields of `Type1` are generated (into `ts`
3. `ts` contains the definition of `Type0`. This declaration works.
4. Then `lookupTypName "Type1"` is called and this returns `Nothing`
5. So a new `DataD` is created with field definitions from  `fn`
6. But the field definitions don't refer to the declarations created in step 2.

Somehow when `genField` is called for `"proj11"` you have to use the declarations returned in `ts` to create the field.

**Update**

Here is the inline version of what you need to do:

```
blah :: Q [Dec]
blah = do
  let ty_int = ConT ''Int
  t0_cname <- newName "Type0"
  proj0_name <-  newName "proj0"
  let t0_rec = RecC t0_cname [ (proj0_name, NotStrict, ty_int) ]
  t0_tname <- newName "Type0"
  let t0_decl = DataD [] t0_tname [] [t0_rec] []

  proj11_name <- newName "proj11"
  t1_cname <- newName "Type1"
  let t1_rec = RecC t1_cname [ (proj11_name, NotStrict, ConT t0_tname) ]
  t1_tname <- newName "Type1"
  let t1_decl = DataD [] t1_tname [] [t1_rec] []

  return [t0_decl, t1_decl]
```

If you expand `$(blah)` it should work and in ghci you'll see:

```
*Main> :i Type0
data Type0 = Type0 {proj0 :: Int}   -- Defined at ...
*Main> :i Type1
data Type1 = Type1 {proj11 :: Type0}    -- Defined at ...
```

The key is in the `t1_rec` assignment. For the type of the field you have to use the same name (`t0_name`) that was used in the `DataD` constructor for Type0.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that once I made a new name for type "Type0", the second call to `lookupTypeName` would return it. And that's not the case. So apparently I'll have to manage `(String, Name)` pairs by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Following version seems to work as intended:

```
genType :: [(String, Name)] -> CType -> Q Type
genType db CInt = return (ConT ''Int)
genType db CDouble = return (ConT ''Double)
genType db (CProduct s t) =
    do
      let 
          res = lookup s db
      case res of
        Nothing -> return (TupleT 0)
        Just n -> return (ConT n)

genField :: [(String, Name)] -> (String, CType) -> Q VarStrictType
genField db (s , t) =
    do
      sn <- newName s
      tn <- genType db t
      return (sn, NotStrict, tn)

todb = map (\(x, _) -> (nameBase x, x))
crit (x, _) (y, _) = nameBase x == nameBase y 

genDecl :: CType -> Q [(Name, Dec)]
genDecl CInt = return []
genDecl CDouble = return []
genDecl (CProduct s t) =
    do
      ts <- fmap (nubBy crit . join) . mapM (genDecl . snd) $ t
      res0 <- lookupTypeName s
      let
          db = todb ts
          res1 = lookup s db       
      case (res0 , res1) of
        (Just _ , Just _) -> return ts
        (Just _ , Nothing) -> return ts
        (Nothing , Just _) -> return ts
        (Nothing , Nothing) ->
            do
              sn <- newName s
              sc <- newName s
              fs <- mapM (genField db) $ t
              let
                  dt = DataD [] sn [] [RecC sc fs] []
              return ((sn, dt) : ts)
```